# Classic ASP com dll error when calling stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic, com

We are migrating our classic asp application from server 2003 to server 2008r2. Our app uses a Classic ASP front end running in 32bit mode connecting to a VB com DLL. I was able to get most things running including connecting to the database. Where I run in to problems is running stored procedures, I get an error 800a01a8 object required error when I call a function in the DLL that calls a stored procedure. I can see that the stored procedure is being called through SQL Server profiler and locks on the database. I can call functions that do direct select/insert statements and they work fine. I can run the stored procedure through query analyzer with the same parameters.

Any ideas?

asp call   response.write Dll.callfunction

VB 6 Dll function

```
Dim cmdStoredProc As ADODB.Command
Dim TheRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strGo As String
Dim strOptionLine As String
Dim objObjectContext As ObjectContext
Dim objResponse As Response
Dim strCurrentID As String

If Not Conn_Good Then Exit Sub
strGo = GetDisplayedText(257, ClassLng, O)
Disconnect 1

If Conn_Good Then
    Set cmdStoredProc = New ADODB.Command
    Set cmdStoredProc.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmdStoredProc.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmdStoredProc.CommandText = "MYTABLESTOREDPROC"
    cmdStoredProc.Parameters.Refresh
    cmdStoredProc.Parameters(1).Value = GUID


    Set TheRS = New ADODB.Recordset
    TheRS.LockType = adLockReadOnly
    TheRS.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    TheRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    TheRS.Open cmdStoredProc

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        O.RaiseErrVB Err.Number, "PromptChangeNAme", "Muser", Err.Description, "MYTABLESTOREDPROC", ""
        TheRS.Close
        Set TheRS = Nothing
        Set cmdStoredProc = Nothing
        Disconnect (2)
    Else
        Set objObjectContext = GetObjectContext()
        Set objResponse = objObjectContext.item("Response")

        ' Begin Form and Select
        objResponse.Write "<form method=""POST"" action="""" name=""ChangeName""><select name=""frmName"" size=1>"


        strCurrentID = ID

        Do While TheRS.EOF = False
            If strCurrentID = TheRS.Fields("ID") Then
                strOptionLine = "<OPTION selected VALUE=" & TheRS.Fields("ID") & ">" & TheRS("NAME") & "</Option>"
            Else
                strOptionLine = "<OPTION VALUE=" & TheRS.Fields("ID") & ">" & TheRS.Fields("NAME") & "</Option>"
            End If
            TheRS.MoveNext
            objResponse.Write strOptionLine
        Loop

        TheRS.Close
        Set TheRS = Nothing
        Set cmdStoredProc = Nothing
        Disconnect (1)
    End If
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

objResponse.Write "</select><br><p><input TYPE=""SUBMIT"" Value=""" & strGo & """ name=""GoSearch""></form>" & vbCrLf

Set objResponse = Nothing
Set objObjectContext = Nothing
```

Comment: Without the code in the VB(6? .Net?) dll, I can only guess that there is a ComCreateInstance that's failing after the proc returns and before the client closes its connection... 

Also, migrating from really old to almost as old seems like a questionable investment to me...

Comment: the code is added to original question   code works in iis 6 server 2003

Comment: Examine (or show) the definition of GetObjectContext() - it appears to be trying to CoCreateInstance something which is then immediately dereferenced - and objObjectContext.item probably where that COM error is being thrown.

Comment: Sorry I know the code works, at least in server 2003. I think there is a configuration error that I am missing, not a code error.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin no Oni after you mentioned GetObjectcontext I went down the rabbit hole and found the answer  http://forums.iis.net/t/1146404.aspx   and then to here  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/04/28/iis-intrinsic-properties-are-disabled-by-default-on-windows-2008-and-windows-2008-r2.aspx   If you migrate your ASP and COM+ application from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008 you may find that your application fails. “Invalid procedure call or  “Object Required.”
The root cause can be related to IIS intrinsic properties